# How do I start the index to a different position in a text file?

Tags: string, vb.net, messagebox

What I am trying to accomplish is to extract specific text from a text file.

Currently what this code outputs is that if parsed, it will display extracted text in a messagebox. It will extract the first 500 characters from the text file and display it in a little messagebox.

The problem is that it starts from the beginning of the text file to extract the text. What I want it to do is to search for the text that states "SUMMARY" in the text file and start from there to extract the first 500 characters.

I believe the problem is that I am missing some necessary code and I'm hoping someone can help me provide it for me please.

```
    Dim start_index As String = "SUMMARY"

    If parse() Then
        MsgBox(tariff.Substring(0, 500))
    Else
        MsgBox("Failed to parse.")
    End If
```

Comment: If this is VBA. You can use `Mid/Mid$` to select a specific index range of characters to select See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function. Alternatively, you could `Left/Left$` if you want the first X characters

Comment: Please don't tag VB.NET questions with VBA.

Comment: Maybe: `Dim s = New String(File.ReadLines(f).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.ToLower.StartsWith("summary"))?.Take(500).ToArray)` ?

Comment: If you don't want to star from index 0 then why are you specifying index 0 when you call `Substring`? If you want to read from the start of specific text then you need to specify the index of that specific text. That really ought to be obvious. If your actual question is how to find that index then you ought to have asked that question and shown the code relevant to it.